# Mysql update max value with group by

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sql-update

I have a simple table that has many rows already:

```
id  grade  ...
1    1     ...
2    2     ...
3    2     ...
4    1     ...
5    1     ...
```

Now i want to add a column `"relative_order"`, which is the order **in that grade**. So the table becomes:

> ```
> id  grade  ...  relative_order
> 1    1     ...       1
> 2    2     ...       1
> 3    2     ...       2
> 4    1     ...       2
> 5    1     ...       3
> ```

After i add the column, all the relative_order becomes 0 first. How can i fill the relative_order column using `update` syntax?

I tried using **inner join**, but failed:

```
UPDATE table AS i
INNER JOIN(
  SELECT max(relative_order) as mOrder,grade
  FROM table 
  GROUP BY grade
) AS j
ON i.grade = j.grade
SET i.relative_order = j.mOrder + 1
```

Comment: You may need to write a cursor.  You are trying to update all records based on a value that, on a per record basis, does not exist.  In other words: to update ID=5, your query assumes ID's 1&2 already exist, but they are not established yet

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use this SELECT query that will return the `relative_order` that you need:

```
SELECT
  t1.id,
  t1.grade,
  COUNT(t2.id) relative_order
FROM
  yourtable t1 INNER JOIN yourtable t2
  ON t1.grade=t2.grade AND t1.id>=t2.id
GROUP BY
  t1.id,
  t1.grade
```

or if you want to update the value, you can join your table with the previous query, like  this:

```
UPDATE
  yourtable INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
      t1.id,
      t1.grade,
      COUNT(t2.id) relative_order
    FROM
      yourtable t1 INNER JOIN yourtable t2
      ON t1.grade=t2.grade AND t1.id>=t2.id
    GROUP BY
      t1.id,
      t1.grade) seq
  ON yourtable.id=seq.id AND yourtable.grade=seq.grade
SET
  yourtable.relative_order = seq.relative_order
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8753c7/1).